# Check if a string is X or is not X

Tags: regex

I can check if a string equals to a given keyword with regular expressions. Here is an example:

```
Regex: /^hello$/
String: hello
Result: matches, as expected

Regex: /^goodbye$/
String: goodbye
Result: matches, as expected

Regex: /^bye$/
String: bye bye
Result: does not match, as expected
```

What I can't achieve is to check if a string is not equal to a keyword. Here are some examples of what I am trying to do:

```
Regex: ^(?!hello).*$
String: bye
Result: matches, as expected

Regex: ^(?!hello).*$
String: bye bye
Result: matches, as expected

Regex: ^(?!hello).*$
String: say hello
Result: matches, as expected

Regex: ^(?!hello).*$
String: hello you
Result: does not match, but should match because "hello you" is not equal to "hello"
```

I think I am close with `^(?!hello).*$` but need a hand on this. Here is another example:

```
Regex: ^(?!fresh\sfruits).*$
String: fresh fruits
Result: does not match, as expected

Regex: ^(?!fresh\sfruits).*$
String: lots of fresh fruits
Result: matches, as expected

Regex: ^(?!fresh\sfruits).*$
String: fresh fruits, love them.
Result: does not match, but should match
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use string comparison, rather than regex?

Comment: I'm guessing this is more out of curiosity and for learning rather than as a practical method.

Comment: Good point but the application I am working on needs set of rules defined in regular expressions. This is not curiosity or for learning, this is a real need :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's just add the failing case to your expression:

```
^(hello.+|(?!hello).*)$
```

So the first bit matches hello followed by anything save the empty string. (I just finished an automata class and can't help but think of it as ε :P). The second bit matches anything not starting with `hello`.

That covers all the possible cases, I think.

Answer (score 1):

`^(?!hello$)` (drop the `.*`)

(...fixed lookbehind/ahead confusion)

Comment: For me in JavaScript `/(?!^hello)$/.test("hello")` returns `true`. In fact, it seems to return `true` for every string.

Comment: `(?!^hello)$` does not match `bye`. The regex should match if the string is not equal to a keyword.

Comment: Aha, was going out the door as I typed it, mixed up some lookahead/behind. Fixed now.